# Drupal image upload fails dues to a max file size limit of 8 bytes

Tags: php, nginx, drupal

Really strange error message. Drupal is brand new installed and running on an Nginx that is also fresh.

I have absolutely no idea where the **8 bytes** are coming from. I set nothing that is kind of `8` in the `php.ini`.

The only thing I set in `php.ini` is this:

```
upload_max_size = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 256M
max_execution_time = 300
```

[image]

So how to fix that image upload limitation? Really lost as there is no detailed error log on this except that message from the image.

### Edit

I found out that the mode of the editor is causing this issue. So in `Full mode` it fails with that error message, but in the `Simple mode` it works.

But I would like to use `Full mode` without that workaround uploading in `Simple mode` before.

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your php.ini is being used? You can check on the phpinfo page at "/admin/reports/status/php"

Comment: Yes. Updated question as the issue only happens in Full mode.

Comment: It seems you are using CKeditor, in which case it could be that the ckeditor module doesn't find your php config and set its max file size limit to a faulty value. So if you are using ckeditor, you can try to set the limit manually via the admin UI at `/admin/config/content/formats/manage/full_html`, or alter the corresponding form (and form_submit, so that an empty value for that setting properly fallbacks to the php.ini setting) in a custom module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @EricLavault, somehow the setting was set to 8. As I can't remember to set it there, I cannot say what changed it. Now works again properly.

[image]